# Can I connect a virtual android device via USB to my local machine?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to emulate an android device, I'm fine with using any third party software, or just the basic AVD from the Android SDK tools.

All I would like, is to know if it's possible for any of these emulators, to let me simulate an USB connection, from that emulated virtual android device, to my computer. I'm trying to make an application and I just have to connect an android via USB to my computer, my physical android's version is too old, so I would really appreciate it if you can help me out, thanks!

EDIT : I am not trying to connect anything via USB to my emulated android device, I am trying to get the actual device, to be simulated as if it were connected via USB to my host machine. Thank you.